# Ignoring the @ symbol when running a MySQL command from C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have the following MySQL command that populates a table with the last 6 matches played by soccer teams:

```
insert into lastxgames
select team, matchdate, hometeam, awayteam, fthg, ftag
from (
  select
    team, soccerdata.matchdate, hometeam, awayteam, fthg, ftag,
    @teamCounter:=IF(@prevHome=team,@teamCounter+1,1) teamCounter,
    @prevHome:=team
  from soccerdata
    join (
      select distinct matchdate, hometeam team
      from soccerdata
      union 
      select distinct matchdate, awayteam
      from soccerdata
    ) allgames on soccerdata.matchdate = allgames.matchdate
      and (soccerdata.hometeam = allgames.team or soccerdata.awayteam = allgames.team)
    join (select @teamCounter:=0) t
  order by team, soccerdata.matchdate desc
  ) t 
where teamCounter <= 6
order by team, matchdate desc;
```

I want to run this from within a C# program, but when I do the query fails as the @ symbol is taken as a query parameter, rather than being treated in the way that MySQL intended (a MySQL variable?).

Within my C# program I am just declaring a string to hold the query and adding it to a MySqlCommand:

```
string insertCommand = @"insert into lastxgames...";
using (MySqlCommand cmdInsert = new MySqlCommand(insertCommand, dcConnection))
{
  cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Is there a way to get C# to ignore the @ symbol so that @teamCounter and @prevHome are not treated as query parameters?

Comment: Could you show how do you use the example text ?

Comment: Edited to include some c# usage info

Comment: What is the error message received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper thing to do would be to make this a stored procedure at the database and have your C# run that sproc.

Comment: I thought that may be the case.

Comment: I've added it as a stored procedure and it works as expected when called from within MySQL. However, when I call it from my C# program it generates the wrong answer (far too many records are copied to the table). There are NO parameters passed into the stored procedure, so I am totally perplexed as to why it behaves in a different manner!

Comment: Further analysis indicates that the stored procedure produces the wrong result when run for the FIRST time but produces the correct result every time thereafter! As the C# code is always the first call (after the connection has been established) it always produces the wrong result. Put in a second call to the same routine in the C# code and it works as expected.